# Log4net get log text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I need get log text from log4net.

For example

> Configuration:
>  %date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] -
>   %message%newline
>  Text:
>  2013-11-25 16:05:22,306 [13] ERROR
>   REJS.Web.Controllers.BaseController [(null)] - Exception
>   System.ArgumentException:

And I need this Text.

can anyone help me?

Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use log4net's `MemoryAppender` which you can use to get back the buffer written.  There is SO thread at [Is there a log4net memory appender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053948/is-there-a-log4net-memory-appender) that describes how you can use it.

Word of caution - you will need to actively manage purging data from it, since if you don't, it'll keep accumulating data until it runs out of memory and your process dies.  Without purging data, it'll essentially create a fantastic memory leak.